# Python: Exporting CSV from web scrape

Tags: python-2.7, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

The code below currently prints everything I want out of the website; however, I am facing difficulty trying to turn it into a CSV that I can work with.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

#fetch top Amsterdam restaurants
driver.get('http://www.eater.com/maps/best-amsterdam-restaurants')

a=[]
b=[]
c=[]

for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//h2[span[@class = "c-mapstack__card-index"]]'):
    restname = elem.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    a.append(restname)

for address in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('c-mapstack__address'):
    restaddress = address.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
    b.append(restaddress)
for content in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('c-entry-content'):
    restdescrip = content.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
    c.append(restdescrip)

q=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(b, b[1:]) if '+31' in y]


q.insert(21,'Raadhuisstraat Amsterdam, Netherlands')
q.insert(25,'Leidsestraat 94 Amsterdam, North Holland 1017 PE, Netherlands')
d=c[1:]

new_dict= dict((a[i], (d[i],q[i])) for i in range(len(a)))
with open('EaterPull-Amsterdam.csv', 'a') as fd:
    writer = csv.writer(fd, 'excel')
    writer.writerow(new_dict.iteritems())
#commented this out to write csv
#for k, v in new_dict.iteritems():
    #print k, v
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
writer.writerow(new_dict.iteritems())
    _csv.Error: sequence expected
```

I feel like this is super simple, but I can't quite wrap my head around what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up solving my problem. k and v were the sequence that the csv module wanted. The code looks like so:

```
for k, v in new_dict.iteritems():
    print k, v
    eater = [k,v]
    with open('EaterPull-Amsterdam.csv', 'a') as fd:
        writer = csv.writer(fd, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow(eater)
```